# What is thee difference between Bing Speech API and UWP Speech API

Tags: azure, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I found two interesting alternatives in order to give to my desktop application the capability to understand some command.

1. Bing Speech API, that is a rest interface to convert speech to text (in order to put the translated text into a search form, for example)
2. UWP Speech API .

But it is not clear the difference in terms of:

A) costs. Cognitive website explains several pricing plans. UWP is free instead?
B) customization: CRIS service, within Cognitive, is customizable. UWP is also customizable? how Can i customize the dictionary?

Let's Do what Mother Microsft sometimes doesn't make : clarity

Thanks a lot guys!
ZAR

Answer (score 0):

> A) costs. Cognitive website explains several pricing plans. UWP is free instead?

Accessing the  `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` namespace to use relative speech  APIs  in UWP app is free. Details for how to use them please reference [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition). And there is an [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) you can reference.

For cognitive service they may have pricing options. But one of the advantages of these cloud-based APIs is that they can be used regardless of the client platform and so can be applicable both to you, as a UWP app developer, but also to a website developer and to a developer who’s wanting to build cross-platform native apps using technologies, such as Xamarin. More details you can reference [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/02/using-speech-in-your-uwp-apps-look-whos-talking/#RxJ53CFqJbK00M2l.97).

> B) customization: CRIS service, within Cognitive, is customizable. UWP is also customizable?

As far as I known, `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition` doesn't provide a [Custom Recognition Intelligent Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/custom-recognition-intelligent-service-cris) same as azure cognitive services have.  Custom Speech Service may need create a custom acoustic model firstly, which may be a collection of speech data with `.wav` format. UWP speech recognition seems like don't provide a such feature. It seems like the [text normalization](https://cris.ai/Home/Help#Transcription%20guidelines%20(en-US)) required by Custom Speech Service could be done in uwp app according to the scenario 2 of the official sample. In my opinion speech recolonization in uwp app has some [constrains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/define-custom-recognition-constraints) can be customized but currently it doesn't have a Custom Speech Service to let you create custom speech-to-text models, tailored to your application's environment, user population, and vocabulary.